# Index out of bounds for various spark operations

Tags: azure, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I'm working on some data (~200GB) using spark in azure databricks. I am able to read the dataset (from blob storage) and modify it in various ways. However, every time I try to store it, either through `.saveAsTable()` or `.csv()` etc. I get this error. I am also getting it while using `.select()` (and various other functions) as seen in the stacktrace.

Any suggestions as to what could be wrong here would be highly appreciated!

**Note** I'm not a spark, azure or python expert so the more explicit the better :)

**EDIT**
Example of code returning this error:

Example 1

```
df=spark.read.csv(f"wasbs://{container}@{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/")

df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("test")
```

Example 2

```
df.write.csv("test")
```

Example 3

```
df.select().where(df['installationId'] == '').count()
```

All of these are giving the same error

```
    Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2838615377381489> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 numInstallationId = df_android.select().where((df_android['installationId'] == '') | (df_android['installationId'] == None)).count()

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in count(self)
    807         2
    808         """
--> 809         return int(self._jdf.count())
    810 
    811     def collect(self) -> List[Row]:

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1319 
   1320         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321         return_value = get_return_value(
   1322             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1323 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    194     def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    195         try:
--> 196             return f(*a, **kw)
    197         except Py4JJavaError as e:
    198             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1449.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 234 in stage 18.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 234.3 in stage 18.0 (TID 1145) (10.139.64.18 executor 15): com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file wasbs:REDACTED_LOCAL_PART@**REMOVED BY ME**.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.logFileNameAndThrow(FileScanRDD.scala:544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:513)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:637)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.$anonfun$hasNext$1(FileScanRDD.scala:359)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:354)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.hashAgg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:136)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:870)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1690)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:873)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:728)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.univocity.parsers.common.TextParsingException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - null
Parser Configuration: CsvParserSettings:
    Auto configuration enabled=true
    Auto-closing enabled=true
    Autodetect column delimiter=false
    Autodetect quotes=false
    Column reordering enabled=true
    Delimiters for detection=null
    Empty value=
    Escape unquoted values=false
    Header extraction enabled=null
    Headers=null
    Ignore leading whitespaces=false
    Ignore leading whitespaces in quotes=false
    Ignore trailing whitespaces=false
    Ignore trailing whitespaces in quotes=false
    Input buffer size=1048576
    Input reading on separate thread=false
    Keep escape sequences=false
    Keep quotes=false
    Length of content displayed on error=1000
    Line separator detection enabled=false
    Maximum number of characters per column=-1
    Maximum number of columns=20480
    Normalize escaped line separators=true
    Null value=
    Number of records to read=all
    Processor=none
    Restricting data in exceptions=false
    RowProcessor error handler=null
    Selected fields=field selection: [0]
    Skip bits as whitespace=true
    Skip empty lines=true
    Unescaped quote handling=STOP_AT_DELIMITERFormat configuration:
    CsvFormat:
        Comment character=#
        Field delimiter=)
        Line separator (normalized)=\n
        Line separator sequence=\n
        Quote character="
        Quote escape character=\
        Quote escape escape character=null
Internal state when error was thrown: line=0, column=20481, record=0, charIndex=5890569
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractParser.handleException(AbstractParser.java:402)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractParser.parseLine(AbstractParser.java:707)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.csv.UnivocityParser.$anonfun$parse$2(UnivocityParser.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.csv.UnivocityParser$.$anonfun$parseIterator$1(UnivocityParser.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.FailureSafeParser.parse(FailureSafeParser.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.csv.UnivocityParser$.$anonfun$parseIterator$2(UnivocityParser.scala:454)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:486)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:492)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:478)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:3247)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:3181)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:3175)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:3175)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1412)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1412)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1412)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3456)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3397)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3385)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:51)
Caused by: com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file wasbs:REDACTED_LOCAL_PART@**REMOVED BY ME**
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.logFileNameAndThrow(FileScanRDD.scala:544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:513)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:637)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.$anonfun$hasNext$1(FileScanRDD.scala:359)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:354)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.hashAgg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:136)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:870)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1690)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:873)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:728)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.univocity.parsers.common.TextParsingException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - null
Parser Configuration: CsvParserSettings:
    Auto configuration enabled=true
    Auto-closing enabled=true
    Autodetect column delimiter=false
    Autodetect quotes=false
    Column reordering enabled=true
    Delimiters for detection=null
    Empty value=
    Escape unquoted values=false
    Header extraction enabled=null
    Headers=null
    Ignore leading whitespaces=false
    Ignore leading whitespaces in quotes=false
    Ignore trailing whitespaces=false
    Ignore trailing whitespaces in quotes=false
    Input buffer size=1048576
    Input reading on separate thread=false
    Keep escape sequences=false
    Keep quotes=false
    Length of content displayed on error=1000
    Line separator detection enabled=false
    Maximum number of characters per column=-1
    Maximum number of columns=20480
    Normalize escaped line separators=true
    Null value=
    Number of records to read=all
    Processor=none
    Restricting data in exceptions=false
    RowProcessor error handler=null
    Selected fields=field selection: [0]
    Skip bits as whitespace=true
    Skip empty lines=true
    Unescaped quote handling=STOP_AT_DELIMITERFormat configuration:
    CsvFormat:
        Comment character=#
        Field delimiter=)
        Line separator (normalized)=\n
        Line separator sequence=\n
        Quote character="
        Quote escape character=\
        Quote escape escape character=null
Internal state when error was thrown: line=0, column=20481, record=0, charIndex=5890569
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractParser.handleException(AbstractParser.java:402)
    at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractParser.parseLine(AbstractParser.java:707)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.csv.UnivocityParser.$anonfun$parse$2(UnivocityParser.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.csv.UnivocityParser$.$anonfun$parseIterator$1(UnivocityParser.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.FailureSafeParser.parse(FailureSafeParser.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.csv.UnivocityParser$.$anonfun$parseIterator$2(UnivocityParser.scala:454)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:486)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:492)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:478)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: hi @Skrettinga, can you please edit and provide the working code?

Comment: Hi @BhanunagasaiVamsi I added some of the code that gives the same error.

Comment: Try checking this file `wasbs:REDACTED_LOCAL_PART@**REMOVED BY ME**`. Is this file following the correct format as other files?   (there is a line says `Error while reading file wasbs:REDACTED_LOCAL_PART@**REMOVED BY ME**`)

Comment: @Emma Well, the file is probably not following correct format. The whole operation I am trying to do is to re-format its contents. I am able to read it in and do stuff with it just not save it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems like the problem was related to reading the blob as a csv. The content of the blob storage was probably not correct csv format so reading as text solved the issue!

```
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").text(file_location)
```

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced same thing in my environment. I got the same error, for overcoming this error. Follow below syntax and reference.

Create a mount location to your storage account with data bricks. Mount creates a separate storage location and also you can perform both read and write operations:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = "wasbs://<container_name>@<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point = "/mnt/<Folder_name>",
    extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net":"Access key"})
```

[image: Ref1]

**Access key**

[image: Ref2]

```
#reading Data

file_location = "/mnt/demo123"

df = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").option("sep", ",").load(file_location)
 display(df)
```

[image: Ref3]

```
#Writing data 
df.write.mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").csv("/mnt/demo123")
```

[image: Ref4]

**Or**

Without mount also you perform Read and write operation

For more information refer this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeNgrBxHmCc) and [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I am still experiencing the same issue. The data that I am reading is not correct format and I am trying to format it using spark and then to store the formated dataframe. It seems wierd to me that I can read a malformed csv-file but I can't store it. Is there anyway to force the dataframe to follow a specific format? I have set a schema and when using .dtypes it seems correct but apparantly there is still something wrong with it since I am not able to save it.

Comment: It don't appear to matter how I create the table, csv-file or otherwise. I still get the same error when trying to store the dataframe.